# Node.js: Which parts of the code are executed following an asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Asynchronous calls are an inherent part of javascript, and using callbacks is often an elegant tool to handle these calls.

However, I am not quite sure how is the branching of code following an asynchronous operation decided. For example, what would happen with the following code?

```
function f(callback) {
   value = some_async_call();
   if (value) {
       callback(value);
   }
   return(value);
}
```

What would happen here? From my short JS experience, `return` would send back an `undefined` value. But suppose that `value` returns true from the asynchronous call, would the callback be called with the right value or with an `undefined` value?

**In other words, is there a rule regarding which operations are executed immediately after the async call, and which are deferred until the value is returned?**

## What have I tried before asking

SFTW for branching asynchronous calls in javascript, but found nothing canonical or decisive.

Comment: i bet that if `some_async_call` returns something before `if(value)` is executed, then it is not an asynchronous task at all.. The way to do it is, rather than test any return from the task, to pass your callback to it (if it is async, it most surely provide an argument for a callback). It would the be rather `some_async_call(callback);` than `value = some_async_call();`

Comment: Is the `some_async_call` a proper asynchronous function, or is it just a function that does some async stuff? If it's the latter, it can't really return a value if the value depends on the async call.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, `undefined` will be returned. You execute your logic after asynchronous operation you should pass your callback into that function. You are trying to use code in synchronous manner and `async/await` comes to the rescue. Assuming that `some_async_call returns` `Promise` you can write:

```
async function f(callback) {
  var value = await some_async_call();
  if (value) {
    callback(value);
  }
  return value;
}
```

In this case your function will return `Promise` of value and also will be asynchronous. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

And even more you don't need to pass a callback. You can `await` your function in client code and execute callback from there.

Regarding branching, the only way you can branch without using `async/await` is to make `some_async_call` accept a callback that accepts the `value` as parameter:

```
function f(callback) {
 some_async_call(function(value) {
   if (value) {
     callback(value);
   }
 });
}
```

And to reiterate once again there is no way to return a value from async method except `Promise`. Or `Observable` in [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html).

Comment: Thanks. Apart from my example, is there a general rule about code flow following an sync call? Is there any official reference regarding branches?

Comment: Async function is like `setTimeout`. It will return immediately. The only and execution will move forward. And the only way to get the value or execute the logic after async operation before `Promises` and `async/await` was to pass a callback. If that's what you mean.

Comment: @AdamMatan, you might also be interested in reading about control flow in node.js http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html.

Answer (score 4):

**update: added a practical difference between the 3 different approaches at the bottom**

let's assume `some_async_call();` is defined as an async function: `async function some_async_call() { ... }`

what this function returns is a `Promise`, which means that `value` is now a promise: `value.then( function(result) { } )`

when i translate this into code:

```
async function some_async_call() { 
    if (theMoonIsInTheRightPosition)
        return Fetch('/api/data/') // this returns a promise as well.

    return false;
}
```

i can now do 2 things:

```
function parentFunction(callback) {
    var promise = some_async_call();
    promise.then( callback );
    return ...; // you can't "return" the value of an async call synchronously, since it is a promise.
}
```

or:

```
async function asyncParentFunction( callback ) {
    var value = await some_async_call();
    if (value)
        callback( value );
    return value;
}
```

however, this transforms the parent-function into an async function as well, which means the immediate return value of that function... is a promise as well.

### Long story short:

You either use callbacks to flow through your asynchronous functions, or promises, or async/await

**callbacks**

```
function doStuff(callback) {
    // do asynchronous stuff
    var result = 100;
    callback(result); // once you're done with stuff
}
doStuff( function(data) { console.log('Im done!', data); } );
```

**promises**

```
function doStuff() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // do asynchronous stuff
        var result = 100;
        resolve(result);
    });
}
doStuff.then(function(data) { console.log('Im done!', data); });
```

**async/await**

```
function doStuff() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // do asynchronous stuff
        var result = 100;
        resolve(result);
    });
}
(async function() { // async/await only works in async functions.
    var data = await doStuff();
    console.log('Im done!', data);
})();
```

as you can see: promises and async/await use the same mechanism and are really worth reading into.

### a practical example of the difference between the three:

**callbacks**

```
function fetchUserWithPosts(userId, callback) {
    fetchUser(userId, function(user) {
        fetchPostsByUserId(userId, function(posts) {
            callback({
                user: user,
                posts: posts
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**promises**

```
function fetchUserWithPosts(userId) {
    return Promise.all([
        fetchUser(userId),
        fetchPostsByUserId(userId)
    ]).then(function(result) {
        return {
            user: result[0],
            posts: result[1]
        };
    });
}
```

**async/await**

```
async function fetchUserWithPosts(userId) {
    return {
        user: await fetchUser(userId),
        posts: await fetchPostsByUserId(userId);
    };
}
```